# PHP session variable issue while using iframe

Tags: php, variables, session, post, iframe

I'm trying to create a contact form inside an iFrame.

The form is loaded first in the iFrame and I use method="POST" target as my next php page which sends a mail. I'm not able to retrieve the session variables in the target page when I tried echoing them.

I looked at other forum threads and tried verifying session id in both pages and they are the same.

Please help!

Edit: Adding Code. I have 2 PHP files:

1.Contact.php

```
<?php

  session_start();

echo "Session ID: ".session_id();

$_SESSION['sesssubject'] = $subject;
$_SESSION['sessmessage'] = $message;
$_SESSION['sessname'] = $name;
$_SESSION['sessemail'] = $email
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Contact Form</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="send_contact.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
          <td width="16%">Subject</td>
          <td width="02%">:</td>
          <td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Message</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="4" id="message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2. send_contact.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();

echo "Session ID: ".session_id();


$subject = $_POST['sesssubject'];
$message = $_POST['sessmessage'];
$name = $_POST['sessname']; 
$email = $_POST['sessemail']; 

echo "hi";
echo $subject;
echo $message;
echo $name;
echo $email;

$to ='<my-email>';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$name);

if($send_contact)
  {
  echo "We've received your contact information";
  }
else 
  {
  echo "ERROR";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep if you need help it's better to show your code , this is how it works on this website.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code here.

Comment: Ok +1 for fixing this, but why do you start new sessions on the contact form before submitting?

Comment: I read that I have to use session_start(); in both pages to carry forward my variables to the next page, and that this will not necessarily start new sessions, but just continue if one is already existing.

Comment: My objective is simple, I just need the 4 variables passed to the second page. It did not happen when I tried without session, so I used it per suggestion in another thread. The same code is not working even when I remove the session details on the top.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, your suggestion worked, thank you. I should have asked my question well ahead before my extensive research into sessions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My objective is simple, I just need the 4 variables passed to the
>   second page. It did not happen when I tried without session, so I used
>   it per suggestion in another thread. The same code is not working even
>   when I remove the session details on the top.

Ok I get it now, get rid of all your Session you don't need them at all

If your going to use the variable being posted from the form do this:

```
<?php

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 

echo "hi";
echo $subject;
echo $message;
echo $name;
echo $email;

$to ='<my-email>';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$name);

if($send_contact)
  {
  echo "We've received your contact information";
  }
else 
  {
  echo "ERROR";
  }
?>
```

It did not work because you used the wrong names for POST variables, it should be the name of your html tags instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Forget ifrmane, I think you are not able to catch the POST data from the HTML.

if you have html file as

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="field_name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

then you need to write an result.php file as we have used result.php in form above as :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['field_name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

make sure you host these both html and php file on a working server, since php is a server side scripting language thus it requires to be hosted.
You can use a localhost server by simply downloading and installing WAMP server for windows, then paste your html and php file in C:/wamp/www/ folder.
Run wamp server and open 127.0.0.1 in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I realized I had to give the code, and have edited my original post. Please see my code, I'm using a PHP webserver to run this.